# How to resize search suggestion field below search input field in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem to resize the search suggestion list box in Bootstrap by CSS.

I'm using a input(search) field in Bootstrap navbar. But I'm facing difficulties while resizing the search suggestion box below the input(search) field.

Sample Image:

[image]

The width of search suggestion field should be upto `Submit` button.

I've tried so far:

`HTML`

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left searchBox">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Raisa Hasan</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Obaidul Islam</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

`CSS`

```
.searchBox .list-group{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a container? Or there is also a grid system that is available. Here is a link to w3 schools tutorial on bootstraps grid system. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This CSS

Make Use of `max-width` property

CSS

```
.navbar-form{
  position: relative;
  max-width:100%;
}
.navbar-form ul.list-group{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Style Accordingly

[link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/vbrLsbu5/4/)